# What is the difference between joining tables using INNER JOIN and setting foreign keys using FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES?

Tags: mysql

To make relational tables in MySQL, what is the structural difference between joining tables using INNER JOIN and setting foreign keys using FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES? Under what kind of specific situations, one must be used while the other one must not? Which one should be used in general case?

Comment: Those are two **completely** different things. And it's not an either/or decision. In any sensible database you use both.

Comment: Best to post that BTW question as a separate question to improve the chance of it getting answered! :)

Answer (score 2):

The two are somewhat unrelated, though a `JOIN` may benefit from being made on a foreign key.

FK references are a tool for forcing the engine to maintain referential integrity. It requires an entry in one table have a value matching the key from another table.

Consider, for example, a Table called "Parents" and a table called "Children". The Children table **must** have a Parent, by definition. So you would create a foreign key constraint from the Children table to the Parent table on some column like "ParentID". This prevents rows from being entered into the Children table which do not have a matching Parent. Likewise, it prevents Parents from being deleted if they have corresponding Children.

[SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

A `JOIN` is a condition in a query or instruction which logically links the two tables, on the given conditions, for the purpose and scope of that query.

So, if you wanted to return the children of a parent by name you might do something like this:

```
SELECT
    parent.name
    ,child.name
FROM
    parent
JOIN
    child
    ON child.parentid = parent.id
WHERE
    parent.name = 'Bob'
```

[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

They are two different things:

**foreign keys** are used to ensure referential integrity and it lets you cross-reference related data across tables

To retrieve data from two tables, you must join them and for joining them you will be using the **primary and foreign key columns**

Answer (score 1):

You *make* a table using the "create table" statement, and you can use FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES statements to explicitly identify the relationship between the current table and others.

You *query* a table using "select ..." statements, when you can use a JOIN statement to link tables to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Those are different things. You should always enforce referential integrity (foreign key relationships) when there are so that you cannot produce invalid records (foreign keys that point to nothing). The `JOIN` is an operation to match records from two tables (or more if combined).